# Java. Инициализация

Tags: java, инициализация

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между вариантами кода? Какой вариант лучше применять? (вместо типа String может быть любой тип)

```
public class SomeClass {
    String string = new String("Some text");
    public SomeClass() {}
}

public class AnotherClass {
    String string;
    public AnotherClass() {
        string = new String("Some text");
    }
}
```

Comment: В зависимости от задачи - разный. Даже ни тот ни другой. Например когда нужно использовать Dependency Injection и оперировать обобщённым классом. Так что ответ: зависит...

Comment: Имена конструкторов должны совпадать с именем класса. Исправьте

Answer (score -1):

Я придерживаюсь правила - вся инициализация в одном месте. Если можно оставить конструктор пустым, то конструктор вообще не пишется:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String s = "value";
    ...
}
```

Если у экземпляров класса есть переменная часть при конструировании, то всё делается в конструкторе:

```
public class ClassB {
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    public ClassB(String s2) {
        s1 = "value";
        this.s2 = s2;
    }
    ...
}
```

Основание для правила - простота чтения кода: для представления о состоянии класса после инициализации не требуется смотреть в несколько разных мест. Порядок инициализации лучше соответствует порядку операторов в коде.

Comment: То есть если переменных 20  и только одна из них как аргумент конструктора - то всё делать в конструкторе? Мне кажется это как раз усложнение жизни) Тем более, если будут наследники класса.

Comment: Код один раз пишут и двадцать раз читают. Да, текста больше, зато читать легче. На наследование обсуждаемый вопрос никак не влияет.

Comment: Прямым образом влияет! Если у дефолтного класса будет наследник и захочется его создавать с конструктором без параметров, то для совместимости у родителя будет такой конструктор - ок, но зато все свойства будут null. А хотелось бы, чтобы, например, тот же `s1`  было инициализированно. И таких влияний ещё кучечка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вы ошибаетесь. При создании потомка будет вызван конструктор родителя. Если его нет, то будет сделана инициализация как описана в классе родителя. Ситуации когда все свойства стали `null` не может быть.

Comment: https://ideone.com/0SqKrA

Comment: Вы создали конструктор, который ничего не делает и вызвали. Зачем? Вы можете так поступить, но мне не понятна цель.

Comment: см. сообщение выше.

Comment: Из конструктора без параметров наследника можно вызвать конструктор с параметрами родителя. Для это не надо вмешиваться в дизайн родителя: [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: Ну и как вы представляете себе вызов конструктора родителя с параметрами, если нужно вызвать конструктор наследника без параметров и чтобы у наследника были все свойства родительского класса уже инициализированные?

Comment: `public ClassB() { super("value_for_s2"); }`

Comment: И откуда это значение `value_for_s2` вдруг возьмётся? А если оно вот нафиг не упёрлось в классе наследнике? Пустой строкой инициализировать? Инициализация ради инициализации? Вы просто усложнили жизнь следующим разрабам, которые должны знать (откуда-то), что при построении наследника надо вдруг (зачем-то) вызвать конструктор с параметрами родителя. А если у родителя есть конструктор с 5-ю параметрами? А для наследника не нужно ни одного? Нужно зачем-то их передавать? Бред. Просто бред

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120492/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).